# Adding an Android Library Project from command line

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I am running an ant-built project targeted at **Android 19**. I'm trying to use the TabLayout introduced in the **Android Design Library** released with Android 5.0.

When I try to build my project from command line, I found that Android Design Library required **appcompat**. I added appcompat, and I removed the resources folders for v21 and v23 because my app only supported v19 (and it was giving me errors). I managed to get Appcompat to build using ant debug, but when I try to build the Design Library, I get errors

```
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/bin/classes
[javac] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/src/main/java/com/somedomain/design/MainActivity.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
[javac]                                ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable activity_main
[javac]   location: class layout
[javac] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/src/main/java/com/somedomain/design/MainActivity.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
[javac]                                    ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable menu
[javac]   location: class R
[javac] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/src/main/java/com/somedomain/design/MainActivity.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
[javac]                       ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable action_settings
[javac]   location: class id
[javac] Note: /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/src/main/java/com/somedomain/design/MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 3 errors
```

Without referencing appcompat, I get this from doing the same thing: (this is why I added appcompat though it is never mentioned)

```
    -code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'backgroundTint'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:23: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:34: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:59: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textAllCaps'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:67: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:71: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:87: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:97: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.
     [aapt] 
     [aapt] /home/yunshen/workspace/ui-android/design/res/values/styles.xml:105: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1'.
     [aapt]
```

I've tried removing /gen and doing update lib-project and clean, but to no avail.

With appcompat, I've listed the dependency in project.properties like this

```
target=android-19
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat/
```

Question

- Why do I get this error
- Does the Android Design Library released with Android 5.0 require Android 5.0? (This would explain my problems)
- Is it safe to remove the v21, v23 resource folders in appcompat so I can build it with target 19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I get this error

Change your `target` to `android-23`. Your build target (what in Android Studio would be called the `compileSdkVersion`) should match that of the Android Support libraries that you are using.

> Does the Android Design Library released with Android 5.0 require Android 5.0?

No. AFAIK, it works back to API Level 7, as does `appcompat-v7`. It needs to be *compiled* against a newer version of Android, as it conditionally uses APIs from newer Android versions when running on a newer Android device.

> Is it safe to remove the v21, v23 resource folders in appcompat so I can build it with target 19?

No.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. About your second point - the project I am building runs on custom hardware that currently only supports v19. By "compile against v23", does that mean I can update to 23 locally and compile once, or will it require the entire project to have a dependency on 23 from now on? (I'm guessing the latter)

Comment: @EricS.: "does that mean I can update to 23 locally and compile once" -- nobody but you is in control over how many times you need to compile, so I do not know what "and compile once means". You need to install the API Level 23 SDK Platform, though. "or will it require the entire project to depend on 23 from now on?" -- there will be a **compile-time** dependency on having a build target of API Level 23. There will **not** be a **runtime** dependency on API Level 23. As I wrote, the code that you are trying to use **runs** back to API Level 7, and so that code will run on API Level 19 as well.

Comment: I understand what you are saying now. About the compile once thing, I meant something stupid that I won't elaborate on. Do you know if it is feasible to reduce the compile-time dependency by using an earlier version of appcompat? Just for the small matter of making other people on the project update to 23.

Comment: @EricS.: "Do you know if it is feasible to reduce the compile-time dependency by using an earlier version of appcompat?" -- yes, older versions of `appcompat-v7` will have older build target requirements, because the newer versions of Android did not exist back then. However, there are **substantial** differences between pre-21 and 21+ versions of `appcompat-v7`. Also, I would expect that `TabLayout` will require API Level 23 for itself, plus expect the v23 edition of `appcompat-v7`. If changing build targets is a problem, use another tab solution, as there are lots of libraries with 'em.